# Struggling with combining parameters using an API?

Tags: javascript

From lines 63 to 83 at https://jsfiddle.net/nn2qmc7t/ I am having trouble using an API in my javascript, I think its the merging of the parameters. I am trying to input via the API which is not amicable regarding the documentation here neither can I get support from the site: https://newsapi.org/docs basically what am I doing wrong here and how do I make all the parameters work from lines 69 to 75?

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink- 
    to-fit=no">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">


    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" 




  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- JavaScript that needs to be loaded first -->

    <script src="js/moment.min.js"> </script>


    <title>feed.football - Quick and easy football news and tables!</title>
  </head>
  <body class="bodyClass">


<!-- Navbar begin: -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #efefff;">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">feed.football</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon-custom"><i class="fal fa-futbol fa-1x"></i></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html"><i class="fal fa-newspaper fa-1x"></i> News <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> <!-- Main news will always be the home page / feed -->
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="tables.html"><i class="fal fa-table fa-1x"></i> Tables</a> <!-- Football tables include results -->
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html"><i class="fal fa-envelope fa-1x"></i> Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Navbar end. -->


<!-- Main content begin: -->

<div class="text-center">

    <h2>Coming Soon!</h2>

    <p>Quick and easy football news and tables!</p>


</div>

<!-- Get news data begin: -->

<script>

var todaysDate = moment(todaysDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
console.log("Todays date is: " + todaysDate);


var url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?' +
          'category=sport' + 
          'country=uk&' +
          'q=football&soccer' +
          'from='+todaysDate+'&sortBy=popularity?'
          'sort by relevance&'
          'apiKey=6b6384493350490abac2f85fb6f584e2';

var req = new Request(url);

fetch(req)
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.json());
    })
</script>

<!-- Get news data end. -->


<!-- Parse news data to HTML begin: -->





<!-- Parse news data to HTML end. -->


<!-- Main content end. -->


<!-- Footer begin: -->

<footer>

<hr></hr>

<div class="text-center">
<em><p><a target="_blank" href="http://NewsAPI.org">News powered by NewsAPI.org</a></p></em>
<em><p><a target="_blank" href="http://jamie.zone">&#169; <script>document.write(moment(todaysDate).format('YYYY'));</script> - Jamie Cropley</a></p></em>
</div>

</footer>

<!-- Footer end. -->




    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->

    <script defer src="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-d84LGg2pm9KhR4mCAs3N29GQ4OYNy+K+FBHX8WhimHpPm86c839++MDABegrZ3gn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>





    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When combining a large number of parameters into a URL querystring, it is much better to use a function as it is pretty easy to make mistakes otherwise:

```
function querystring() {
    return Object.keys(params).map(function(k) {
        return encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + 
        encodeURIComponent(params[k]);
    }).join('&');
}
```

And create the URL like so: `var url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?' + querystring({ category: 'sport', country: 'uk', q: 'football&soccer', from: todaysDate, sortBy: 'popularity'`... and so on

Here is another mistake:

```
.then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.json());
})
```

`response.json()` is actually a promise that resolves with the parsed JSON data so you need to await for it too.

```
.then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
})
.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: Better answered than mine, go with this one :)

Answer (score 0):

OK you have several issues here, not 100% sure I can completely resolve your problem but should be able to get you going down the right path.

```
var url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?' +
          'category=sport' + 
          'country=uk&' +
          'q=football&soccer' +
          'from='+todaysDate+'&sortBy=popularity?'
          'sort by relevance&'
          'apiKey=6b6384493350490abac2f85fb6f584e2';
```

First, you can only use one `?` in your URI so have multiple is going to cause all kinds of problems.

Second, you have to be careful when using `&` as its also a special character that is used in URIs, in your case you need to convert it to %26 unless your API has a special and operator it uses in its queries.  Also, you need to have a `&` between each of your parameters, you are missing several.

Now I did not get any results back when I ran this but as you can see I did get a 200 response so no errors.

[image]